# Call a component function from react-native's Navigator buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is a question that I've seen floating around in quite a different contexts without any direct solution. I've also been asked by a few people that I was showing some samples to how I got the Navigation to execute the code I wanted it to, as most of them have rolled with third-party solutions or created their own navigation headers using a `<View>`.

For the question to have some context, this is what we're trying to accomplish:

```
class Example extends Component {
    componentRouteMapper() {
        switch(route.id) {
            case 'home' return <Home navigator={navigator} { ...this.props } />
        }
    }

    navigationBarRouteMapper = {
        LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
            return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onLeftPressed.bind(this)}>
                <Text>Left Button</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        },
        RightButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
            // ... Same as left
        },
        Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
            return <Text>{route.id}</Text>
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Navigator initialRoute={{id: 'home'}}
            renderScene={this.componentRouteMapper}
            navigationBar={
                <Navigator.NavigationBar { ...this.props } 
                    routeMapper={this.navigationBarRouteMapper}/>
            }

    }
}
```

Naturally you're going to want to be able to handle the navigation bar logic from within the context of the rendered component. In this case: `<Home />` and we're going to want to be able to share the state/props from that components active instance.  Executing the above code will cause an error, even if you have `onLeftPressed()` declared in your home component, like so:

```
export default class Home extends Component {

    onLeftPressed() {
        console.log('Pressed left button')
    }

    render() {
        return <View>
            <Text>Home Component</Text>
        </View>
    }
}
```

So the question at hand is... How do you call `onRightPressed()` from the `navigationBarRouteMapper`

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, and while there are other approaches such as injecting the component in the Router, considering my applications use `Redux` passing in the `connect()` method to the Route object is a bit of a hassle.

So, I came up with a simple, yet effective solution that works regardless of what you're using to manage your state. **Injection**. That's right, just Inject whatever you need to call straight into your `navigation` object.

The `navigation` object can be accessed from within your component through `this.props.navigator` and lucky for us, Javascript objects are mutable and passed by reference by nature. This means any changes we make to the navigator object will be reflected in the navigator that is injected into the `navigationBarRouteMapper`

So, first lets change a little bit of code:

```js
navigationBarRouteMapper = {
    LeftButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        return <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigator.__onLeftNavButtonPressed}>
            <Text>Left Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    },
    RightButton: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        // ... Same as left
    },
    Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        return <Text>{navigator.navTitle || route.id}</Text>
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I've changed the `onPress` value from `{this.onLeftPressed.bind(this)}` to `{navigator.__onLeftNavButtonPressed}` now obviously you can change the names that are being used, but I like the double underscore prefix.

You'll also see that I changed the Title to return `{navigator.navTitle || route.id}` instead of just `route.id` and what this means is that it will use the `navTitle` property from navigator if it's available, and if it's not then it will use the id of the route at the top of the stack.

So now lets make changes to our `<Home />` component so that our navigationBarRouteMapper executes the code that we want it to.

```js
class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        var navigator = this.props.navigator
        navigator.navTitle = 'Home'
        navigator.__onLeftNavButtonPressed = this.onLeftPressed.bind(this)
    }

    onLeftPressed() {
        console.log('Pressed left button')
    }

    render() {
        return <View>
            <Text>Home Component</Text>
        </View>
    }
}
```

As you can see the only thing that was changed was we added a `constructor(...)` that injected the function and title into the `navigator` object. Now if you click on the left button you will execute the `onLeftPressed` function inside of your `Home` component.

However you can abstract this a little more by creating a custom component subclass. For example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class NavComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.warn('Constructed')
        var navigator = this.props.navigator
        navigator.navbarTitle = this.__onNavTitleRequested();
        navigator.__onLeftNavButtonPressed = this.__onLeftNavButtonPressed.bind(this)
        navigator.__onRightNavButtonPressed = this.__onRightNavButtonPressed.bind(this)
    }


    __onLeftNavButtonPressed() {

    }

    __onRightNavButtonPressed() {

    }

}
```

This ensures that the left and right navigation button functions are always set, even if they do nothing which will prevent application errors due to attempting to call an undefined function. You will also noticed that there is a reference to `__onNavTitleRequested` however there's no default function for this, this is to ensure that the subclass will have to have `__onNavTitleRequested` defined, or else the application will not run correctly. This is to safe you from having a Component with an incorrect title in the title bar, since if you do not set the title it will always use the last set title.

An example of implementing this would be as follows:

```js
import React from 'react'
import NavComponent from './path/to/nav-component.js'

export default class Home extends NavComponent {
    __onNavTitleRequested() {
        return 'Home'
    }

    __onLeftNavButtonPressed() {
        console.log('Left navigation button pressed')
    }

    __onRightNavButtonPressed() {
        console.log('Right navigation button pressed')
    }

    render() {
        return <View>
            <Text> Home Component </Text>
        </View>
    }
}
```

This will register an event to the Left/Right button and set the title for the Home component. You can inject more information into the Navigator object too, such as if you wanted to have a `__hasNavigationBar` function that returns true or false to hide the entire navigation bar, or perhaps a `__rightNavButton` function to return the components to be displayed on the right button instead of just a TouchableOpacity button.

As I stated earlier, there's other ways to do this, but considering I'm using Redux with my application this way seemed the easiest, and I've had no problems with it.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative way to do this would be to use an eventbus like react-native-event-listeners. I was able to solve the problem this way, and it is much simpler than [Hobbyist's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39254220/366904).

Basically, the way it would work is that the button would send a message to a receiver, and then the receiver (which is in the context of the component) would perform the necessary actions.